# Can the Yamaha RX-V673 output to headphones and speakers at the same time?

Tags: speakers, headphones

Can the Yamaha RX-V673 output to headphones and speakers at the same time?

My problem is that as soon as I connect the phones, this cuts the sound from the speakers. For my application, I really need both. The RX-V673 manual does not address this situation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question.

The manual says "Connecting a set of headphones automatically mutes the receiver's speaker outputs."

I guess that I will need two amps and have the headphones on the separate unit.